# Mysql query different random conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, random

I need to have random question from my question bank. I have a table, QUESTION, with column: questionType. I need to get random questions from my table depending on the request of the user.

For example, he chooses, questionType: ['Identification', 'Multiple Choice'] and number of questions per questionType: ['10', '20'].

So I need to query random 10 questions from column questionType with value Identification and another 20 random questions from column questionType with value Multiple Choice.

I have this sql statement:

```
SELECT question FROM QUESTION WHERE questionType = 'Identification' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

So how can I add the condition:

```
questionType = 'Multiple Choice' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20
```

Can you please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT question FROM 
(
(SELECT question FROM QUESTION WHERE questionType = 'Identification' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT question FROM QUESTION WHERE questionType = 'Multiple Choice' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20)
) T
ORDER BY RAND()
```

See demo in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c808/9).

Comment: Good solution. Remove the semicolons and better use UNION ALL instead of UNION.

Comment: It says: ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: @user3094292: Edited my answer. See the demo in fiddle.

Comment: Just giving a name to the result of inner query as 'T'. Then selecting question from 'T'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Thanks for your help. It solves my problem.  But can I know what does 'T' means? What is this for?

Comment: The inner query returns a table containing 10 questions of type 'Identification' followed by 20 questions of type 'Multiple Choice'. So we are giving a name 'T' to this temporary table. Then we are selecting from these results (table T) in random order. Hope you got what I mean.